# CSS Blend Background with Parent Background

Tags: css

I have a `div` identified by `#front`.

It is inside a `div` identified by `#back`.

`#back` is a canvas that constantly changes.

I'd like `#front`, a square, plain square to *take the colour of the parent and invert it*.

E.g. if the background is white, the square should be black.
If the background is black, the square should be white. If the background is partially white and partially black, the square should be partially black and partially white.

I have tried `background-blend-mode: overlay` and `mix-blend-mode: screen` on the `#front` element but these had no effect.

Is this possible in any way?

HTML: 
`<div id="parent>  <div id="child">   </div>`

CSS:

```
#back { 
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   background-image:url('http://example.com/image.png');
   background-size:cover;
}

#front {
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: Show us your code......

Comment: @ArjanKnol- there we go.

Comment: Still, we need more code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ArjanKnol- there's nothing in terms of code for me to show. I've added a code example but it doesn't exactly add to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use white for the front element, and mix-blend-mode difference:

```css
#back { 
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/);
   background-size:cover;
}

#front {
   width:400px;
   height:300px;
   display:block;
   background-color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div id="back">
<div id="front">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've done web development for years now and I don't know how I've never come across "mix-blend-mode". That property is magical.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea using SCSS: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/dRqVVQ

**CSS (SCSS)**

```
// set background color here
$color: pink;

body {
  background-color: $color;
}
.child {
  background-color: invert($color);
}
```

> op mentioned that color of back (canvas, or body in your case) will change constantly...

OP hasn't detailed how the the colour of the canvas will actually be changed. What I'm thinking is that if you manipulate $color then there are ways of automatically recompiling SCSS.

[scssphp](http://leafo.net/scssphp/) might be one possibility and [here's how one developer](http://stephencoakley.com/2014/05/22/using-sass-in-php-projects) used it to convert SCSS to CSS on the fly. There are WordPress SCSS to CSS plugins as well, maybe there's one which would be a good match for what's required.

Comment: op mentioned that color of back (canvas, or body in your case) will change constantly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MaulikGangani, please see my updated suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First of all JavaScript is used. and jQuery is also included because i cant find a way to get background of div in real-time using vanila js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            invert color
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #back {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: #000;
        }

        #front {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: #000;
          filter: invert(100%);
          -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="back">
            <div id="front">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //get elements
        var front = $('#front');
        var back = $("#back");

        // make sure #front & #back's background color is same all the time
        setInterval(function(){ 
            var backColor = back.css('background-color');
            front.css('background-color', backColor);
        }, 500);

        // change background color of #back for testing
        setTimeout(function() {
            back.css('background-color', '#fff');
        }, 2000);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You can decrease/increase 500 according to your needs in setInterval.